# How do I make an app to intent in foreground in Kiosk mode App

Tags: android, android-intent, kiosk, kiosk-mode

Currently, working on Kiosk app in which I set an onclickevent of a button which opens map app from phone. But the thing is it stays in background. I need to open the app in foreground. The below code is using,

```
String strUri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + "37.423156" + "," + "37.423156" + " (" + "37.423156" + ")";
intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(strUri));
intent.setClassName("com.google.android.apps.maps", "com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the package name of the google maps into used packages list and set the lockTaskPackages of the DevicePolicyManager object you used. Below is a function where all packages are added.

```
    protected DevicePolicyManager mDpm;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    protected void setUpAdmin() {
        mDpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        ArrayList<PInfo> packages = getPackages();
        ArrayList<String> usedPackages = new ArrayList<>();
        for (PInfo pack:packages){
            usedPackages.add(pack.pname);
        }
        if (!KioskModeApp.isInLockMode()) {
            ComponentName deviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);
            mDpm = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
            if (!mDpm.isAdminActive(deviceAdmin)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, deviceAdmin);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            usedPackages.add(getPackageName());
            if (mDpm.isDeviceOwnerApp(getPackageName())) {
                try {
                    mDpm.setLockTaskPackages(deviceAdmin, usedPackages.toArray(new String[0]));
                    boolean res = mDpm.setStatusBarDisabled(deviceAdmin, false);
                    //mDpm.setLockTaskFeatures(deviceAdmin, DevicePolicyManager.LOCK_TASK_FEATURE_NOTIFICATIONS);
                    Log.d("Tag", "" + res);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    clearDeviceOwner();
                }
            }
            else {
                Log.d("Kiosk Mode Error", getString(R.string.not_device_owner));
            }
        }
    }
```